# CSS - Displaying <img> and <div> inline

Tags: html, css, inline

I have a **div**, and inside it, I have a **img** element and another **div** element with *h3* and *p* elements (no problem with them):
The HTML:

```
<div id="imgandtext">
    <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-hlvQp1p4RwQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABQ/FmK4byxMObk/photo.jpg"/>
    <div id="text">
        <h3>the h3 title</h3>
        <p>The paragraph to put INLINE with the img and under the h3</p>
    </div>          
</div>
```

And I want to put the img and the div called 'text'.

I tried different methods, including the **display:inline** and it always resulted into the elements being displayed one under another.
How do I fix this? (note: I want to conserve the h3 being above the p element)
Thank you in advance, all help is needed and appreciated.

Comment: `display:inline-block`?

Comment: display:inline-block doesn't do anything in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use floating:

```css
#imgandtext > img {
    float: left;
}
#imgandtext, #text {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Using `float: left` to the image will place it at the left of `#text`.

But to make sure the floating element doesn't overflow `#imgandtext` in case the image is taller than `#text`, you need `#imgandtext { overflow: hidden; }`.

And in case `#text` is taller than the image, you may need `#text { overflow: hidden; }` if you want it well aligned.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x46H4/)

Comment: Probably because it's a rudimentary answer to a very rudimentary question that shouldn't be asked (and already has been asked/answered probably a dozen times) on StackOverflow and 18.4k-rep users should know better. But I wasn't the one who downvoted you.

Comment: Wasn't me, your answer helped, thank you! Tho I do not know what the overflow: hidden is for?

Comment: @TylerH I tried to find an answer through google search, this search, and other sites, but i saw nothing that helped yet

Comment: @user3722861 - overflow hidden makes sure that if some content of an element continues (overflows) outside of the boundaries of that element (e.g. text outside of the div it's in), that overflowing part of the content is hidden so it doesn't mess up the look of your website.

Comment: I truly don't understand that downvoting.. downvote the question, not the answer, if the answer is correct it is correct. (Go ahead mock me for not having enough rep to understand it or whatever, I think I understand just fine the downvoter has trouble directing his/her displeasure about the question.. I'm pretty sure downvoting a perfectly legitimate answer is not part of the StackOverflow Regiment no matter how ridiculous the question is)

Comment: Well if not here where am I supposed to ask my questions? i don't see many Q&A sites for beginners,besides, you can't directly be good at something and sometimes i need support just like anyone